# Circuit Simulation for a circuit that take a 10KHz input

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I can't seem to get the amplitude right can someone help me.

Using the Circuit Wizard circuit simulation software, devise a circuit that
takes as input a 10 kHz square wave of 1 V amplitude and uses a
series resistor/capacitor combination to ‘shape’ (take the hard
edges off) the waveform.Choose resistor and capacitor values such that approximately two-time constants have elapsed.

Comment: And why not include a picture of that circuit here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by that last part:

> Choose resistor and capacitor values such that approximately two-time constants have elapsed.

Anyways, is this smooth enough for you?

[image: square wave smoother]

Here's the netlist:

```
V1 N001 0 PULSE(0 1 0 0 0 50u 100u)
C1 N003 0 1µ
R3 N002 N003 1k
C2 N002 0 1µ
R1 N001 N002 1k
.tran 0 5.001 5 10u
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: mmm around 300uV peak to peak... quite low isn't it?